# MATCH and INDEX to return index number 2 Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, match, user-defined-functions

I tried with the combination of `CONCATENATE`, `INDEX` and `MATCH` function, to get an overview table of which employees works which function a day.

Here is the setup:

[image]

And this should be the resulting table:

[image]

This is the formula I made:

`=CONCATENATE(INDEX($B$5:$B$10,MATCH($B2,C$5:C$10,0)))`

And obtain only the first index:

[image]

How can a return index 2 respectively: name3 and name5?

I have an Excel version prior to the 2016 version, and can't use the `TEXTJOIN` or `CONCAT` function.

**EDIT**

I tried to make the formula work even though the VBA solution works as well:

This is what I get to work:

`=IF(COUNTIF(C$5:C$10,$B2)=0,"",IF(COUNTIF(C$5:C$10,$B2)=1;INDEX($B$5:$B$10,MATCH($B2,C$5:C$10;0)),INDEX($B$5:$B$10,MATCH($B2,C$5:C$10,0))&CHAR(10)&INDEX($B$5:$B$10,SMALL(MATCH($B2,C$5:C$10),ROWS(C$5)))))`

It gives the correct solution in this case (assuming there are at most 2 matches), however it's fragile.

I tested it in a larger setup, where it returned the same name twice, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Any idea, why that's the case?

Comment: What about VBA solutions?

Comment: @Andreas I would definitely prefer a formula to handle it. However in lack of a better alternative it may be a sufficient solution. I haven't tried with a VBA or investigated the possibilities in that direction.

Comment: That is how SO works sometimes. Sadly most of the times they can't give the feedback that could be useful.

Comment: I really would like to know. So I can improve my question.

Comment: Thank you for your useful help Andreas, and have a nice weekend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing pretty at all. But it does work.

User defined function.
Place this code in a module

```
Function name_find(func As String, namerng As Range, searchrng As Range)
    
    For Each r In searchrng
        If r.Value = func Then
            name_find = name_find & Chr(10) & Cells(r.Row, namerng.Column).Value
        End If
    Next r

End Function
```

and use the formula:

```
=name_find(C4,C9:C14,D9:D14)
```

[image]

Remember to enable line breaks in the cell. It took me a while to understand why it didn't work :-)